# How to configure ngx-highlight.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following the guide to setup ngx-highlight.js:
[ngx-highlight.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs)

When I reach the step "Import highlighting theme" in the guide, I find that my project is using .css instead of .scss, so I don't think `@import...` can be put into my styles.css.

So how should I do this for .css file?

Answer (score 0):

You can include any CSS file in your Angular app by adding it to the `styles` array in your `angular.json` file under `projects » YOUR_PROJECT_NAME » architect » build » options`.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular8-example-app/blob/master/angular.json#L25